# What is the difference between public smtp server and DNS-MX record?

Tags: email, smtp

Let's start with an example:

[Gmail SMTP server](https://www.lifewire.com/what-are-the-gmail-smtp-settings-1170854) address is (I will call it public below):

> smtp.gmail.com

But if we take a look at the DNX-MX record of gmail.com we will see the following addresses:

> alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
>   alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
>   alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
>   gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
>   alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.

1. What is the difference between public and DNS-MX addresses?
2. Why Gmail doesn't use smtp.gmail.com in DNS-MX addresses?
3. Why Gmail doesn't use DNS-MX addresses as public?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you connect to smtp.gmail.com you are connecting to a Mail Submission Agent.  Typically, you would connect to the MSA on port 587.  You do this when you want to send email that appears to come **FROM** your GMail account.  You need to have a GMail account to do this, of course.

The MSA address doesn't need to be published in DNS in a way that associates it to gmail.com.  If you don't have an account, they don't want you to use it.  If you do have an account, they'll tell you where the MSA is.

When you connect to the MX addresses, you are connecting to a Mail Transfer Agent.  Typically, you would connect to the MTA on port 25. You do this when you want to send email **TO** a GMail account.  It could be your own account, but most of the time it isn't - in fact, you don't need to have your own GMail account to do this.

The MX records are published in DNS so that every MTA in the world can look up Google's MTAs and route email to them.